# path environment для system service

Tags: linux, debian

Не могу понять почему PATH не меняется:

```
[Unit]
Description=web site
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mf
Group=sudo
Type=notify
Restart=on-abort
RestartSec=5s
WorkingDirectory=/home/website
Environment=PATH=/home/mf/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/home/mf/node_modules/.bin:$PATH exec sudo ./website'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Добавляю PATH в `Environment` и добавляю PATH в `ExecStart`, но в результате в website скрипте пишет `myscript not found in path` и вывожу PATH `fmt.Println(os.Getenv("PATH"))` и действительно PATH не изменился.
Как изменить PATH при запуске website.service?

Comment: за systemd не скажу, но `bash`'у в `exec` с таким синтаксисом переменную передать не получится... или `/bin/bash -c 'export PATH=bla-bla; exec my_cmd`, или `/bin/bash -c 'PATH=bla-bla my_cmd`... кроме того `sudo` сам ресетит PATH (как и почти всю среду)... вот скажи, !!нахрена!! запускать модуль с пониженными привилегиями и !сразу! их повышать вот таким костылём??

Comment: @Fat-Zer не могу запустить website скрипт который использует порт 80 без sudo

Comment: просто стартуй модуль от root'а сразу... если это программа, то можно просто дать ей мандат... а если это действительно скрипт, то для чего-либо серьёзного стоит использовать какой-нить полноценный веб сервер, а не какую-то наколенную поделку...